# Uncaught exception: <NSRangeException> valueAtIndex:inPropertyWithKey: index != 0 for non-toMany key

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am getting this exception message:

* Uncaught exception:  valueAtIndex:inPropertyWithKey: index != 0 for non-toMany key

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Google is not giving me any results for this exception.

**Edit** Adding Code

when the control comes to the return statement in:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
      objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                            row:(int)row {
if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"Methods"])
  {
    return [plistArray_ valueAtIndex:row inPropertyWithKey:@"functionName"];
  }
return [plistArray valueAtIndex:row inPropertyWithKey:@"address"];
}
```

Comment: I would love to help, but I need to know what exactly is causing this problem.  Post some code please!

Comment: What are the contents of your `plistArray` and `plistArray_` instance variables?

Answer (score 0):

If your property do not return collection of objects specified index needs to be 0.

```
This actually works with a single-value key as well if index is 0. The method valueIn<Key>AtIndex: is used if it exists.
```

In other worlds. Some of your attributes returns just an object, and your row value is bigger then 0.